# Reading flink MapState key values from multiple threads within process element throws ConcurrentModification Exception

Tags: apache-flink

In my flink job i am keeping data in mapstate for few minutes for further processings, Within the process element I need to execute set of operations with help of mapstate values, So I use multiple threads to process with help of the mapstate contents. Threads are not modifying the stat, it  fetches only the key values causing CocurrentModification exception also this TTL exception comes before the COnfigured TTL time also, logs below.

```
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to incrementally clean up state with TTL
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Futur`enter code here`eTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.XXXXXX.processResults(DataProcessor.java:198)
    at com.XXXXXX.processElement(DataProcessor.java:151)
    at com.XXXXXX.processElement(DataProcessor.java:1)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.processElement1(CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processRecord1(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.lambda$new$0(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor$$Lambda$753/1478413652.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:182)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:311)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$$Lambda$706/2073221180.runDefaultAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:187)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:470)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to incrementally clean up state with TTL
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlIncrementalCleanup.stateAccessed(TtlIncrementalCleanup.java:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlStateFactory$$Lambda$789/1622849283.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlMapState.getWrapped(TtlMapState.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlMapState.get(TtlMapState.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.UserFacingMapState.get(UserFacingMapState.java:47)
    at com.XXXXXX.treamFunctions.findPreviousData(DATAExecutor.java:216)
    at com.XXXXXX.previousVal(DataExecutor.java:175)
    at com.XXXXXX.$FlinkStreamFunctions.execute(DATAExecutor.java:107)
    at com.XXXXXX.evaluateFunction(ExpressionEvaluator.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlIncrementalCleanup.runCleanup(TtlIncrementalCleanup.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlIncrementalCleanup.stateAccessed(TtlIncrementalCleanup.java:58)
    ... 17 more
```

java apache-flink`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Flink's state abstractions are not designed for concurrent accesses and should not be shared between multiple threads.

The long answer is that Flink's state abstractions are not simply a `Map` or a value container which only store some values. Under the hood when the user access Flink state through these abstractions multiple things can happen. For example, if you have configured TTL it will ensure that the TTL has not expired. Moreover, it will make sure that you get the right state value depending on the current key if you are using keyed streams. Depending on the `StateBackend` operation the abstraction might have to read state from disc and to deserialize it for you.

Having said this, it is still possible to share the actual state value between threads given some conditions. If your threads are only consuming the state but not writing it, then you could read the state out and pass the actual value to the other threads.

If you need to write updates from the concurrent threads back to state, then things become a bit more complicated. What you have to ensure is that you access the state from Flink's `Task` thread. Moreover, you have to ensure that you are processing the right key when you want to write state back from a `FutureTask` into Flink state. Hence, you need some bookkeeping which establishes a mapping between keys to concurrent tasks. Be aware, though, that this might become quite tricky especially if you want to ensure a proper failover behaviour.

Alternatively, you could take a look at Flink's [async I/O operator](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html). When using the async I/O operator you cannot access state from the operator. You would have to output the results and keep state in a downstream operator.